# Illegal unit of measure for pdfpages package

Tags: errors, pdfpages

I am having some trouble with an error message that I am receiving and was hoping that someone could provide some advice. The code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[grid, gridcolor=red!50,subgridcolor=green!20,gridunit=pt]{eso-pic}
\usepackage{pdfpages,picture}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\bigO}[1]{\ensuremath{\mathop{}\mathopen{}\mathcal{O}\mathopen{}\left(#1\right)}}

\begin{document}
 \AddToShipoutPictureFG*{
    \AtPageLowerLeft{
        \setlength{\fboxrule}{.5}  
        \setlength{\fboxsep}{.5}
        \put(50pt,500pt){
            \makebox(0,0){%
            \fcolorbox{red}{yellow!20}{%
            \begin{minipage}{3cm}
               \end{minipage}}
            }%
        }
    }
}
\includepdf[pages=1]{dyngraphcon_A8_ts.pdf}      

 \AddToShipoutPictureFG*{
    \AtPageLowerLeft{
        \setlength{\fboxrule}{.5}  
        \setlength{\fboxsep}{.5}
        \put(50pt,500pt){
            \makebox(0,0){%
                \fcolorbox{red}{yellow!20}{%
     \begin{minipage}{3cm}
            \end{minipage}}
                }%
            }
        }
    }
    \includepdf[pages=2]{dyngraphcon_A8_ts.pdf} 



\end{document}
```

Basically, the pdf file is a reference to another document contained in the folder and I wasn't so sure how to include it here so that it is universal... but nonetheless, the error message that I am receiving is given by: 
"Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \includepdf[pages=1]{dynagraphcon_A8_ts.pdf}".

I know that it isn't something wrong with the pdf file as I have tried others and still ran into the same issue. Also, in case it helps, the compiler I am using is TeXstudio but I also ran into the same issue with TeXshop.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: the error is occurring *before* the reported code.  i believe the complaint is about the two commands `\setlength{\fboxrule}{.5}    \setlength{\fboxsep}{.5}` where one would expect something like `.5pt` or `.5em`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the error is occurring before the reported code.

the complaint is about the two commands

```
\setlength{\fboxrule}{.5}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{.5}
```

where one would expect something like `.5pt` or `.5em`.  (of course, you
will need to adjust these suggestions to what is appropriate.)

this occurs twice in this example, so be sure to fix both places.